What to do with Hora Token
About a year ago I moved my Hora Token from Idle Miner to my MetaMask wallet Actually I thought I had lost all the Hora because it didn’t show up as far as I was concerned So just this morning I was messing around in MetaMask and low and behold my Hora showed up There is approximately 7000 tokens I can’t move it out or do anything with it really I want to just get rid of it for cash,that’s if it’s worth anything Another thing that’s happened is the Hora token is hard to find sometimes in MetaMask I know it’s there but it’s playing hide and go seek

Search the token in the public markets and evaluate if it is worth the trouble. On Uniswap v3 it is quite low, it doesn't seem valuable enough to pay the transaction fee required for a swap.
